# Shared local dependency in Android library

Tags: android, build.gradle, aar

I'm working on a set of Android libraries that share a local library.

Basically, I have a Library A and a Library B, which both depend on a Library C

```
   A   B
   ^   ^
   |   |
    \./
     C
```

Library A, B, and C are all in the same Android project.

Initially, libraries A and B can both have the following in their `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    api project(path: ':common')
    ...
}
```

However, this only works when building libraries A and B *internally*. If I deploy them as packages and use them in external projects, I get this error:

```
Could not find my_package_directory:library_common:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/my_package_directory/common/unspecified/common-unspecified.pom
       ...
     Required by:
         project :app > com.my_company.project:library_a:1.0.0
```

I guess it makes sense since library C was released with the same version number as A and B (1.0.0) and not "unspecified".

How do I properly depend on my shared local library?

Answer (score 0):

What I did which I think is close to a solution:

I tried changing library A and B to depend on a specific version of library common (the most recent), but I still wanted to use the local version of the common library when working on my libraries.

To enable this I wrote some code which determines if my working directory contains any changes or if the head of my Git Repository is not a tagged release.

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder
import org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException

import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevObject
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevTag
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git

boolean useRemote() {
    Repository repo
    try {
        repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
                .readEnvironment()
                .findGitDir(project.projectDir)
                .build()
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | RepositoryNotFoundException ignore) {
        return false
    }

    def git = Git.wrap(repo)
    def head = repo.findRef(Constants.HEAD).getTarget()

    // No commits?
    if (!head.getObjectId()) return false

    // Check to see if uncommitted files exist
    if (git.status().call().hasUncommittedChanges() || !git.status().call().getUntracked().isEmpty())
        return false

    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)
    List<ObjectId> tags = git.tagList().call().findResults { ref ->
        RevObject obj = walk.parseAny(ref.getObjectId())
        ObjectId id = null
        if (obj instanceof RevTag) {
            // Annotated tag
            id = obj.getObject().getId()
        } else if (obj instanceof RevCommit) {
            // Lightweight tag
            id = obj.getId()
        }
        id
    }
    walk.close()

    // Check to see if head is tagged
    if (!tags.findAll { (it == head.getObjectId()) })
        return false
    return true
}
```

(very much inspired by [this project](https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version))

Then in my dependencies clause:

```
if (useRemote()) {
    api "com.my_company.project:common:${project.ext.libraryVersion}"
} else {
    api project(path: ':common')
}
```

This seems to work internally but when I use it externally I still get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: package_repository:common:unspecified
```